# How can I open a specific section of html in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html

To open the html of the current page in a new tab, you can create a like so:

https://plnkr.co/edit/0LJxYPc2LalmmRlPFvzE?p=info

```
<a href="" target="_blank">See HTML in seperate Tab</a>
```

This opens ALL of the html. What I would like to do is the following

```
<p>I hope this html doesn't show up in my new tab!</p>
<div>
<p>This html should show up in my new tab</p>
<a href="somehow only the div I'm in" target="_blank">See HTML of ONLY the div in seperate Tab</a>
</div>
```

The new tab should only show the html in the div if that wasn't clear yet.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You may use a modal instead or render a page on the serverside through passed in url params.

Comment: An HTML page cannot render only part of its DOM on load. You could use JavaScript to immediately hide certain aspects, however. And if you have access to something like PHP, you could output content to the DOM based on content on a secondary page, essentially dynamically creating a partial. It really depends on what you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge ok perhaps some scripting is necessary. Ill add a javascript tag. Maybe theres a way to do it in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTML page cannot render only part of its DOM on load. You could use jQuery to immediately hide certain aspects, but they would still get loaded into the DOM. And if you have access to something like PHP, you could output content from one page to another page, essentially dynamically creating a partial.

Personally, I would tackle this with AJAX, wherein you can specifically only grab a portion of one page that gets loaded into another:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'page1.html',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(data) {
       var content = $('body').append(data).find('p:second-of-type');
       $('body').html(content);
   }
});
```

Resulting in:

```
<body>
  <p>This html should show up in my new tab</p>
</body>
```

On the secondary page.

Hope this helps! :)